# GNU Assembler for PDP-11 does not check BR range limit

Tags: gnu-assembler, pdp-11

I'm using gas to build a project for the PDP-11 compatible machine.
And I noticed unexpected behavior in some cases. But I'm not sure - is it a bug or I did something wrong.

First, it does not display an error or warning in a case when the destination for `BR` instruction is out of range(the maximum range for the jump is -128 to +127 words).

Another issue, `~` prefix operator supposed to do complementation(bitwise not) but I'm getting an error "undefined reference to `~1`" when I try to do something like thins `BIC $~1,R0`